# Excel - saving Workbook very slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of workbooks that are particularly slow when I save them (10 - 30 mins). I know the reason that they are slow is because they have lots of INDEX, MATCH formulas which are linking to another, closed workbook.

The workbook takes 19 seconds to open and about 10 seconds to recalculate when a date is changed (before improvements, recalculation time was about 50 seconds). I just can't seem to speed up the saving time of the workbook.

I have tried to find a way to replace the INDEX, MATCH formula's with VBA code that imports the data when a change is detected, but apparently it isn't possible to import data from a closed workbook, so that doesn't work for me.

I did have the formula's set up as =INDEX( , MATCH( , , )) However I have changed this to have a MATCH column and then lots of INDEX formulas, this has cut the recalculation time down to a fifth of what it originally was and the opening time in half, but if anything the saving time is longer.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If the workbook which is the source of the links is also open at the time of opening/saving that should make a big difference. Or are you saying that this is impractical? Personally I always ensure that any linked workbooks are open simultaneously when doing work in a file with such external links.

Comment: Having the data store workbook open doesn't seem to make a difference unfortunately, I think the amount of resource the data store is using whilst it is open is offsetting any benefit gained from having it open.

Comment: You say INDEX/MATCH formulas? Not array versions thereof, I trust? And how many such formulas are we talking about? Any volatile functions (e.g. OFFSET, INDIRECT, TODAY, NOW) in your workbook?

Comment: Nope no INDIRECT or OFFSET functions, just straight up INDEX and MATCH to do a lookup based on a date. The real reason why I have loads of INDEX and MATCH formulas is because I need to SUMIFS the data that is pulled through by the INDEX and MATCH, that sounds a bit bonkers I know but the INDEX and MATCH works when the data store is closed and SUMIFS doesn't, the data store has to be open for the SUMIFS alone to work, so I pull the data through using INDEX and MATCH and then SUMIFS. Maybe it's that process which is wrong and there's a better way?

Comment: 756,612 INDEX MATCH formulas

Comment: That's a lot! True, SUMIF(S) doesn't work on closed workbooks, but SUMPRODUCT does. And all SUMIF(S) constructions can be replaced with  equivalent SUMPRODUCT ones. True, SUMPRODUCT is not quite as efficient, and it does mean that you can't pass an abitrarily large range as you can with SUMIF(S), though that simply means you'll have to take care with the size of the ranges being passed, and if it avoids the need for all those INDEX/MATCH constructions then it may well be worth investigating.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for how to run a macro when a cell's value changes:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612

From there you can have the macro open the new workbook, add your `INDEX MATCH` formulas to the cells in your original workbook, copy and paste as values, then close the other workbook.  That way your file is all values instead of formulas, which will increase speed significantly.

To increase performance of the macro while it runs, add this to the beginning of the code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Then add this to the end:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and see what sort of save times I can get to, the data store workbook is far larger than the workbook I am having trouble with, it just doesn't have any external links whatsoever, but it still takes a while to open and close it (1 min open, 1 min save & close), this should still be quicker than the save time I am experiencing but will increase my recalculation time because every time I recalculate the large data store will have to be opened and currently recalculation time is sitting pretty at about 10 seconds.

Comment: Just a bit of context, a lot of people at work use these spread sheets in read only mode, they don't have to save the work book but they do need it to recalculate quickly. I'm the only one who needs to save the work book when a change is made so I can't trade off save time for recalculation time.

Comment: I guess it depends on how often cell values change in the workbook that's giving you trouble.  If it's very rare, my answer should be a good option.  If it's frequent, then you may want a separate macro you can manually kick off.
Also, from what I'm understanding it sounds like Pivot Table on your data store workbook might be a better option than a ton of `INDEX MATCH` formulas

Comment: It's quite often, despite my excel experience I never use pivot tables very much. How would I use it effectively in this scenario? As above the workbook has 756,612 INDEX MATCH formulas.

Comment: I don't know without seeing your data set and desired result, but this may help:

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

In my experience, I try to steer clear of the `INDEX MATCH` combo since it slows down the file so much, even though it is very useful.  I tend to use that only when a `VLOOKUP` won't work because the value I need is left of the lookup value

Comment: It's difficult to explain but there is a logic behind the design of both spread sheets. Basically, the worksheets with loads of INDEX and MATCH formulas replicate the layout of worksheets in the data store exactly, except the lookup values (dates) down the left hand side. The data store has dates going from cell 6:2927 but the workbook with the INDEX and MATCH formulas only needs a range that goes from 6:735. But the dates are not static.

Comment: Also, I used INDEX and MATCH so I could write 1 formula with relative column references and absolute row references in the INDEX range so that it could just be copied across.